# MYSQL Queries using LIKE

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to use PHP to query MYSQL for some exact matches and some partial matches. The following code give me perfect exact matches for all fields:

```
$results= mysql_query ("SELECT * 
                          FROM companyinfo 
                         WHERE id='$Companyid' 
                            OR companyname='$Companyname' 
                            OR contactname='$Contactname' 
                            OR address1='$Address1' 
                            OR city ='$City' 
                            OR primaryphone='$Primaryphone' 
                            OR email='$Email'")
```

I would like to be able to do a partial search on Company Name. Using the following code allows me to achieve this except it messes up all other search fields.

```
$results= mysql_query ("SELECT * 
                          FROM companyinfo 
                         WHERE id='$Companyid' 
                            OR companyname LIKE '%{$Companyname}%'
                            OR contactname='$Contactname' 
                            OR address1='$Address1' 
                            OR city ='$City' 
                            OR primaryphone='$Primaryphone' 
                            OR email='$Email'")
```

Anyone have any hints?

Comment: "it messes up all other search fields" --- what does it mean? If you want to partially match a city, why do you use `LIKE` with `companyname`?

Comment: you shouldn't quote int values, assuming your id is an int...

Comment: Sorry for being vague. For example if I do a search for id 20 it works fine in the first example but not the second. The second example displays all records in the table for basically all searches except for companyname. Sorry city was a typo I meant companyname

Comment: With your current query what your saying is find me all the fields in which the company name contains $Companyname or where either of the other fields match. How is this query going to be beneficial? Because it will find you all the companies that contain the characters mentioned in $Company name and also those that match the other fields.

Comment: tried this yet? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm reading into your question a bit here, but I'm pretty sure `$Companyname` is empty, leaving you with the query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM companyinfo 
WHERE id='20' 
OR companyname LIKE '%%'
OR ...
```

That `WHERE companyname LIKE '%%'` will match *anything* non-null; making all the other `OR` conditions moot. You'll need to set up a special case where `$Companyname` is empty, or simply not include unused search criteria in the predicate.

---

This is all, of course, assuming that `OR` is really what you mean to do here. In most searches I've done, the assumed UX has been to match *all* criteria I specify, not *any*. The only time *any* would apply is with a single search input, which your case clearly is not.

I should also include the obligatory "Your query is subject to SQL injection. Stop putting what is clearly user-input into dynamic queries, and use parameters instead." comment here as well.

Comment: You are right, $companyname is empty. That makes sense. I will look into one of the solutions you suggested. As for your sql inj comment, I'm only learning and this is my first test project but I am aware of this issue and plan to spend more time reading up on it and fixing my code. 

There is a form with 7 search fields and 1 submit button. I would like to return any matches even if only one of the fields has criteria.

Comment: I don't think OR is what you want here then, if two fields have criteria you'd get the union of both matches, not the intersection.

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT * FROM companyinfo 
WHERE id LIKE '%$Companyid%' OR companyname LIKE '%$Companyname%' OR address1 LIKE '%$address1%' OR city LIKE '%$city%' OR primaryphone LIKE '%$primaryphone%'OR email LIKE '%$email%';
```

Comment: I only want partial match on one value.

Comment: use AND operator in my case