# PHP MYSQL Query Issues

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm stumped as to why my PHP mysqli queries are not returning consistent results.

For example I run the following query and it gives me all the email addresses.

```
SELECT id, companyname, contactname, address1, city, postalcode, primaryphone, email 
FROM installers 
WHERE email LIKE '%@%'
```

If I run this query I get no results:

```
SELECT id, companyname, contactname, address1, city, postalcode, primaryphone, email 
FROM installers 
WHERE email LIKE '%gmail%'
```

Both queries work fine when executed locally on the database. Any ideas of where to look next would be much appreciated.

Updating with code as requested:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
$search_output = "";

include '../sqlconnect.php';

if(isset($_POST['searchquery']) && $_POST['searchquery'] != ""){
$searchquery = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['searchquery']);
if($_POST['category'] == "id"){

    $sqlCommand = "SELECT id, email FROM installers WHERE id = '$searchquery'";

} else if($_POST['category'] == "email"){

    $sqlCommand = "SELECT id, email FROM installers WHERE email LIKE '%$searchquery%'";
}

    $query = $conn->query($sqlCommand) or die($conn->error.__LINE__);
    $count = $query->num_rows;

if($count > 1){
    $search_output .= "<hr />$count results for <strong>$searchquery</strong><hr />$sqlCommand<hr />";
    while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
        $id = $row["id"];
        $email = $row["email"];
        $search_output .= "

        <ul class=list-group style=font-size:13px>
            <li class=list-group-item> <strong>Company ID:</strong> &nbsp $id
            </li><li class=list-group-item> <strong>Email:</strong> &nbsp $email</li>
            </ul>

        ";
            } // close while
} else {
    $search_output = "<hr />0 results for <strong>$searchquery</strong><hr />$sqlCommand";
}
}
?>

<!doctype html>


<body>

<!-- body-content -->
<div class="body-content"><div class="section-inner">

<strong><div style="padding-left:5%; padding-bottom:10px; font-size:24px">Search</strong></div><br>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" class="form`horizontal">

    <div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
        <label for="id" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Search Term</label>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
          <input type="text"  name="searchquery" class="form-control" id="searchquery" placeholder="Type search term here.."></div>

                <div class="col-md-4"> <button type="submit" name="search-btn" class="btn btn-default btn-default">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Search
                </button>

             </div>
           </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Search category:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <select class="form-control" name="category" id="category">

                    <option value="id" selected="selected">Company ID</option>
                    <option value="email">Email</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>

    <?php echo $search_output; ?>
```

Comment: Well he's query code is there, just not formatted.

Comment: *"For example I run the following query and it gives me all the email addresses."* - In a `.php` file or via PHPmyadmin or similar?

Comment: Plus, you tagged this as `mysqli` yet your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24988218/) contains `mysql_*` functions; *questionable.*

Comment: Are there actually  with gmail emails in your database?

Comment: Ya Fred. I'm trying to follow best practices. Should I not be using mysqli?

Comment: Ke Vin - yes there are gmail addresses. I'm not that dumb

Comment: Yes you should be using `mysqli_` yet if your code contains a mix of both `mysqli_` and `mysql_` functions, you can't do that; they do not mix together in the same code, including DB connection. Everything must be `mysqli_`

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything as well as `or die(mysqli_error())` to `mysqli_query($con)`

Comment: it is completely separate code. All from scratch and has nothing to do with code in any of my previous questions despite any similarities you might see in var names and such.

Comment: Then show us your code then, what you've shown us isn't enough. Plus, if you're using this in conjunction with a form, we'll need to see that also.

Comment: `LIKE '%$searchquery%'";` to `LIKE '%".$searchquery."%'";` try that.

Comment: Still the same results unfortunately. If i search for '@' or '.com' I get results. Searching for just 'gmail' or 'hotmail' returns 0 results

Comment: Instead of `$count = $query->num_rows; if($count > 1){` try replacing that with just `if($query->num_rows){` along with my other suggestion.

Comment: Thanks a ton Fred, that resolved the issue. I spent a lot of time looking at that code but didn't even consider that. Can you post that as the answer? I will accept.

Comment: You're welcome, you mean about `if($query->num_rows){`? or about just the `LIKE '%".$searchquery."%'";` or both?

Comment: I know the issue now. Obviously I don't have much data in my database. I also swapped if($count > 1) with if($count > 0) and that worked too. Yes you resolved my issue I would mark you answer correct. Sorry still getting used to using stack and new to coding in general. Bare with me folks I'm trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per OP's request, comment(s) to answer option to close the question.

Instead of `LIKE '%$searchquery%'";` change it to `LIKE '%".$searchquery."%'";` but either should work, as they have in my test.

Nota/edit: *"The count would never be greater than 1 when searching for ID because it is primary key. Resolved by `if($query->num_rows)` The wildcards weren't working properly because they needed to be concatenated with the var $searchquery."* / OP's comment.

Yet, instead of `$count = $query->num_rows; if($count > 1){` replace it with just `if($query->num_rows){`

Even using `if($count > 0)` would work, since you're looking to see if results are more than zero, meaning one or more, and `if($query->num_rows)` would act the same way; if rows found containing your query.

What was probably happening was that, if your column only contained "one" Gmail address, then using `> 1` would be FALSE. Use `>0` if TRUE (if row contains query of one or more).

---

Another method instead of `if($count > 0)` is `if($count == true)` which also works.

Comment: I had 2 issues. The count would never be greater than 1 when searching for ID because it is primary key. Resolved by if($query->num_rows)

The wildcards weren't working properly because they needed to be concatenated with the var $searchquery.

Please correct me if i'm wrong. If not. Thanks again Fred.

Comment: @user3863088 You're very much welcome and that makes a lot of sense, which is why I left a few methods intact in my answer. However, I have made a note of it in my answer for any future readers. Thanks for the update.

Answer (score -1):

Would it be that there isn't any email with gmail?
If not, you could try this following codes, I hope it worked for you.

```
$queryform = "SELECT * FROM installers WHERE email LIKE '%".gmail."%'";
```

Comment: It could just be a text or string to check on, isn't it?

Comment: Your answer would almost be right if gmail was a variable (would be $gmail), the OP is actually looking for the string gmail, that isn't his problem.

Comment: @Jolene 1. if you would have used $gmail your query might run 
2. OP has written the same thing which you are trying to write

Comment: Ah so string and variable would have different results? I'm sorry, I didn't realize that. I thought it would be the same.